# converting TrueType Macintosh Language Codes to BCP 47 language tags

Tags: locale, truetype, ietf-bcp-47

Truetype fonts use "Macintosh Language Codes" to describe the language of localised strings in the "name" table.  A list of language codes can be found in [in the TrueType spec](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html#:%7E:text=Macintosh%20Language%20Codes).  I need to convert these language codes to [BCP 47 language tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).  Is there a table somewhere which shows the corresponding language tags for each code?  Or some pre-existing code which does this translation somewhere?  Or maybe a MacOS API which can translate codes to tags for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLocaleIdentifierFromScriptManagerCodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543446-cflocalecreatecanonicallocaleide?language=objc) to map from legacy IDs to BCP 47 tags.

Edit by the OP: the following code works for me.

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CFAllocatorRef alloc = CFAllocatorGetDefault();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
        CFLocaleIdentifier bcp47 = CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLocaleIdentifierFromScriptManagerCodes(alloc, i, -1);
        const char *s = CFStringGetCStringPtr(bcp47, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        if (s) {
            printf("%d: \"%s\",\n", i, s);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do I need to put in as the `RegionCode`?

Comment: None of the language codes in Apple's TT spec mention any region. Try leaving that set to nil / 0.

Comment: It turns out that the `RegionCode` must be `-1` (not `0`).  With this choice, everything works.